# logos and logou - what's the difference?

Tags: greek, logos

What's the difference between 'logos' and 'logou'? 1 Pet 1:23

Logos appears approx. 39 times in NT. as word, reason, speaker, account, matter

> 1 John 1:1 '...concerning the Word (logou) of Life'

Logou approx. 27 times as word, reason, speaker, account, matter

The bible uses both words which seem to mean the same thing, but obviously there is a reason for picking one over the other in original texts.

Comment: I am struggling to understand this question.  "logou" (of word) is just the genitive of "logos" (word).  Please clarify the question.

Comment: Are you asking about whether "logos" is personified (as in John 1:1 and possibly 1 John 1:1), vs, not personified (as 1 Peter 1:23)??

Comment: I'm asking what the language difference is. Nothing more or ulterior. Explain it in simple terms please.

Comment: Greek is an [inflected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) language.

Comment: Logos means *word*, and logou means *word's*.

Comment: Well that's easy to grasp - how come no one else could state what you suggest is so apparent? So why don't we read the plural in the bible? We do, but not very often it seems

Comment: @Lucian Not quite, the genitive would mean "X's word".

Comment: @curiousdannii: The genitive of X is indeed X's.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer needed only comment to satisfy the question.

Answer (score 4):

My "colleagues" are correct. This is essentially an easy question if you know Greek grammar. For the sake of argument, I will assume you have not formally studied Greek grammar—but of course, correct me if I am wrong.

The chart below shows you conjugated forms of the Greek word λόγος  (‘logos’).

I am not a Greek professor, so I might have the Greek grammar police correcting me here, but I will try to break this down for you in a simple manner.

The chart has 5 rows—one row for each case: **Nominative**, **Genitive**, **Dative**, **Accusative**, and **Vocative**... (and to complicate things further, some grammars will throw in Locative and Instrumental—but let’s keep things simple).

**Nominative** in the first row means the basic form of a word—unconjugated so you have ‘word’ (or a word) or ‘words.’

**Genitive** case in the second row expresses possession; so, you have ‘word’ or ‘words’ of [somebody]—word or words belonging to someone.

**Dative** case in the third row is the case of the indirect object; so you might have I say a word to [somebody].

**Accusative** case in the fourth row is used when the word is a direct object; so, you have ‘a word.’

**Vocative** is the case of direct address and it is lacking an example for ‘word’ because ‘logos’ is (typically) not used in the case
of direct address

[image: chart showing the Greek noun cases]

I hope this  helps to answer your question.

Sources:

Machen, J. Gresham. *New Testament Greek for Beginners*. The Macmillan Company, 1951.

Answer (score 4):

Koine Greek is a highly inflected language.<sup>1</sup> With respect to substantives,<sup>2</sup> this means that the ending of a substantive will change in spelling in relation to its case. This is called declension.<sup>3</sup> Bullions defines case as “the state or condition of a noun with respect to the other words in a sentence.”<sup>4</sup> Koine Greek is understood to have five cases: “the Nominative, Genitive, Dative, Accusative, and Vocative.”<sup>5</sup>

In a lexicon, words are generally arranged alphabetically according to lemma.<sup>6</sup> The lemma of a substantive is its form as declined in the nominative case and singular number. Hence, one would find the word λόγος as a lemma in a lexicon.

[image: Screenshot, LSJ, p. 1057]

A substantive declined in the nominative case is generally used as the subject of a sentence. It could also, among other things, be a predicate nominative, functioning as a vocative, etc.<sup>7</sup>

[image: Bullions, §137, p. 201]

The genitive case has a variety of functions, by far more than the nominative. In 1 Peter 1:23, the word λόγου is declined in the genitive case because λόγου (the object of the preposition διὰ) is being governed by the preposition διὰ (διά).<sup>8</sup> The preposition διά followed by a substantive in the genitive case can have several meanings, one of which is to indicate the means by which something is done.

On the preposition διά, Thayer notes,<sup>9</sup>

[image: Thayer, p. 132–133, διά]

Hence, διὰ λόγου can be understood as “by the word” or “by means of the word.” The preposition διά also governs objects of the preposition declined in the accusative, but that is not the case here, as we would instead read λόγον (accusative) instead of λόγου (genitive).<sup>10</sup>

In 1 John 1:1, the word λόγου occurs again, but this time, it is the object of the preposition περὶ (περί).

On the preposition περί, Thayer notes,<sup>11</sup>

[image: Thayer, p. 501, περί]

Hence, περὶ τοῦ λόγου can be understood as “about the word.” That is, “we have heard...about the word.”

> What’s the difference between λόγος and λόγου?

Semantically, there is no difference in meaning; they are simply different cases of the same lexeme. However, syntactically, they differ as the subject of a sentence and the object of a preposition, respectively.

Long story short, introduce yourself to Koine Greek by investing in a biblical Greek grammar.<sup>12</sup> You can return and re-read my answer. The cloud will have removed itself by then, and things will be clearer.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Black, Ch. 2, §12, p. [10](https://books.google.com/books?id=41j7siCRS0QC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false)
<sup>2</sup> Aaron & Fowler, p. 902: “a word or word group used as a noun.” In Koine Greek, adjectives and participles may also function substantively (i.e., as nouns).
<sup>3</sup> When a substantive inflects, it is said to decline. When a verb inflects, it is said to be conjugated. According to Wikipedia on “[inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection)”:

> The inflection of verbs is called conjugation, and one can refer to the inflection of nouns, adjectives, adverbs, pronouns, determiners, participles, prepositions and postpositions, numerals, articles etc., as declension.

<sup>4</sup> Bullions, §11.3, p. [15](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ZkXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false)
<sup>5</sup> *id.*, p. 16
<sup>6</sup> *Oxford English Dictionary*, “lemma,” 2. c.,: A lexical item as it is presented, usually in a standardized form, in a dictionary entry; a definiendum.
<sup>7</sup> Bullions, §137, p. [201](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ZkXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q&f=false)
<sup>8</sup> *Oxford English Dictionary*, “govern,” 13.: transitive. *Grammar*. Of a word, esp. a verb or a preposition: to have (a word or a case) depending on it; to require (a certain case or mood) in a dependent word.
<sup>9</sup> Thayer, p. [132–133](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q&f=false)
<sup>10</sup> *id.*, p. [501](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA501#v=onepage&q&f=false)
<sup>11</sup> cf. Matt. 13:21: διὰ τὸν λόγον
<sup>12</sup> William D. Mounce’s [*Basics of Biblical Greek*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0310537436) is a decent introductory grammar of biblical/Koine Greek.

#### References

Aaron, Jane E.; Fowler, H. Ramsey. *The Little Brown Handbook.* 11th ed. London: Pearson, 2010.

Black, David Alan. [*Learn to Read New Testament Greek.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=41j7siCRS0QC) 3rd ed. Nashville: B&H Publishing Group, 2009.

Bullions, Peter. [*The Principles of Greek Grammar: Comprising the Substance of the Most Approved Greek Grammars Extant, for the Use of Schools and Colleges.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ZkXAAAAYAAJ) 21st ed. New York: Pratt, 1851.

[*OED Online.*](https://oed.com/) Oxford University Press.

Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing mysterious going on here. As Dottard pointed out, this is just a simple matter of the grammatical use of a noun in the genitive case which demonstates possession as opposed to the nominative case which identifies the subject in a sentence. As the old saying goes, "Sometimes, a sigar is just a sigar."

Comment: seriously! can you give an example that I might understand?

Comment: Perhaps I could if I understood precisely what it is you are trying to figure out. Your question is nothing more than a grammatical one. Are you looking for some deep theological implication you feel may be attached to the use of the genitive case of logos? If that is what you are looking for, I am afraid you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: for crying out loud. stop reading into it. Just explain the differences in plain English. Like you could explain the difference between run and ran for eg couldn't you? Well do the same for this

Comment: It is really as simple as this. Grammatically, Peter could not use the nominative case in this verse. That would have been equivalent to saying, "I borrowed he car." Grammatically, this would make no sense. Rather, you would say, "I borrowed HIS car."

Comment: @user48152 - As we have been trying to point out, "logos" and "logou" are exactly the same word with the same meaning.  Logos is nominative, meaning it is always the subject of a sentence; Logou is genitive meaning that we are talking about something that belongs to or is associated with logos.  That is all!